# Javascript only producing last value of json encoded array

Tags: php, javascript, json, pdo

here's the PHP/PDO.

```
    try {





    $query = 'SELECT Date,Close FROM DY_AAPL LIMIT 5';


    $sth = $db->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();


    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $result_array=array();
        $result_array[]=$row['Close'];

    /*    $num = $row['Close'];    */

        echo json_encode($result_array);



    }


    }catch (PDOException $e){

        echo 'ERROR ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

When I attempt to access the array using javascript, it's only outputting the last value in the array. Any pointers?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       var myjson = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>');

        document.write(myjson); 

    </script>
```

I thought it might have something to do with 'JSON.parse,' but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no reason to use `JSON.parse()` like that.  You can just drop the JSON directly into  the JavaScript source as the value of the "myjson" variable.

Comment: Pointy, if I wanted to pass the JSON to an array, would the variable simply be - "var myjson = [<?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>];"

Comment: If you wanted to put the object value inside a JavaScript array, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$result_array = array();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $result_array[]=$row['Close'];

   /*    $num = $row['Close'];    */

}

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

…instead of initializing and outputting the array in each loop turn.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your doing the json encode within the while-loop. Place it outside the loop so the entire array get encoded.

Also, you're initializing the array within the while-loop. Which means that it will overwrite itself each time it loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should echo your end result, not every iteration:

```
   while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $result_array=array();
        $result_array[]=$row['Close'];


    }
 echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your PHP:

```
    try {
        $query = 'SELECT Date,Close FROM DY_AAPL LIMIT 5';
        $sth = $db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute();

        $result_array=array();
        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $result_array[]=$row['Close'];
        }
        echo json_encode($result_array);

    }catch (PDOException $e){

        echo 'ERROR ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```