# json encoded php array returns undefined in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

This is a follow up to a [previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571491/javascript-only-producing-last-value-of-json-encoded-array)

I'm attempting to pass some data to javascript via json_encode.

I thought I would be able to put the data in to a javascript array as follows:

```
    var data = [<?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>];
```

But when I try to call values they return as undefined. I imagine that it might be putting the data as a singular string inside the array.

If anyone can provide advice that would be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$result_array` is an array in php, then you just need to do:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($result_array); ?>;
```

Comment: You are a saint and a scholar. Darwin award for dumbest developer goes to me. (Thanks)

Comment: Welcome back Daedalus, stack overflow won't let me yet.

Comment: @spm Purpose of 'welcoming me back', when I've only been here once?